# Pandas DataFrame apply returns None values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

The input dataframe example goes as follows:

```
 .   pitch_num  pitch_type   px       pz    pitch_type_prev px_prev pz_prev
 0    1.0          NaN      NaN       NaN         0            0       0
 1    2.0          FF      0.416.    2.963        0            0       0
 2    3.0          FF     -0.191     2.347        0            0       0
 3    4.0          FF     -0.518     3.284        0            0       0
 4    5.0          FF     -0.641     1.221        0            0       0
```

I want to be able to go through the dataframe and get the previous pitch, so I created the function and used apply as shown below:

```
# build the function
def prev_pitch(df):
    for i  in range (1000):
        if df.loc['pitch_num'] > 1:
            df.loc['pitch_type_prev'] = df.loc[i, 'pitch_type']
            df.loc['px_prev'] = df.loc[i, 'px']
            df.loc['pz_prev'] = df.loc[i, 'pz']

# run the function using the apply() method 
df_prev_pitch = df_prev_pitch.apply(lambda x: prev_pitch(df_prev_pitch), axis=1)
```

Why are the returned df column values None? How to fix this?

```
0      None
1      None
2      None
3      None
4      None
```

Comment: Because you are returning nothing from the `prev_pitch` function and hence value assigned to df_prev_pitch is None.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, do you want?

```
df[['pitch_type_prev', 'px_prev', 'pz_prev']] = df[['pitch_type', 'px', 'pz']].shift(1)
```

Output:

```
   .  pitch_num pitch_type      px     pz pitch_type_prev px_prev  pz_prev
 0        1.0        NaN     NaN    NaN             NaN     NaN      NaN
 1        2.0         FF  0.416.  2.963             NaN     NaN      NaN
 2        3.0         FF  -0.191  2.347              FF  0.416.    2.963
 3        4.0         FF  -0.518  3.284              FF  -0.191    2.347
 4        5.0         FF  -0.641  1.221              FF  -0.518    3.284
```